# python script to list EBS snapshots created based on select date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, snapshot

I have searched through StackOverflow and found most examples were using Boto, which is almost deprecated. I am trying to list EBS snapshots created in the last 24 hours (eg. yesterday) using Boto 3.

```
import boto3
import json
import dateutil
from datetime import date, timedelta
import collections

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    source_region = 'ap-southeast-1'
    snapshot_client = boto3.client('ec2', source_region)    

    semalam = (date.today() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')
    ebsAllSnapshots = snapshot_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])

    for snaplist in ebsAllSnapshots['Snapshots']:
        strdate = snaplist['StartTime'].date()
        if (strdate <= semalam):
            print snaplist['SnapshotId']
```

The error I got is `TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to tuple`

the variable strdate did return list of snapshot creation dates, for example:

```
2018-06-10
2018-06-10
2018-06-10
```

Comment: This line: `semalam = (date.today() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')` does not create a datetime object. Instead it creates a tuple. To get a datetime object, change that line to: `semalam = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).date()`. You need to import datetime for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error since semalam is a tuple consisting of date values and on line,

```
if (strdate <= semalam):
```

you are trying to compare it with a datetime object.
Try looping through the tuple values like,

```
strdate = snaplist['StartTime'].date()
for i in semalam:
   if(strdate<=i):
     proceed as usual
```

Make sure the right methods are being called from datetime module